# How to write efficent data to a hdf5 storage?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I try to save a 2 dimension array with 20000 x 30000 size but my computer can't handle this process and die when I run the script.
I have a 8 GB Ram Windows7 machine with Python 2.7 64 Bit (Anaconda install).
Can I do some optimization here?

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

ROWS = 20000
COLUMNS = 30000
VALUES = [1, 5, 10]
db_file = 'db.h5'

f = h5py.File(db_file, 'w')

val = np.full((ROWS, COLUMNS), 0)

for t in ["t1", "t5", "t10"]:
    group = f.create_group(t)
    group.create_dataset("mydata", data=val)
del val
f.close()
```

Comment: `my computer can't handle this process and die`  - Is that all you can tell us about the failure?  No error messages, either from python or the operating system?  Have you tried it with a much smaller array?

Comment: with a smaller array (2000x3000) it works fine. With "die" I mean the computer is unusable (freezed). No error messages.

Comment: What if you make 3 copies of `val` (full size), and no file action?

Comment: I'd also play with `flush` and `driver`.